# How can I create or change polynomial coefficients

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have this code and I want to edit it to do something else:

```
def pol(poly, n, x):
    result = poly[0]

    #Using Horner's method
    for i in range(1, n):
       result = result * x + poly[i]

    return result
#Let us evaluate value of
#ax^3 - bx^2 - x - 10 for x = 1
poly = [5, 9, -1, -10]
x = 1
n = len(poly)

print("Value of polynomial is: ", pol(poly, n, x))
```

I wonder how can I can change the coefficients of the polynomial. And this code just calculates:

```
x^3 and x^2
```

How can I make this code calculate for example this polynomial:

```
p(x) = 5x^10 + 9x - 7x - 10
```

or any polynomial in Python?

Comment: The subject of calculations involving polynomials with computers has been heavily studied. Unless you are doing this as a school exercise, or something like that, may I suggest  that you use the facilities in a library such as sympy?

Comment: ı know symppy thinks, you can  do some about polynomials.but ı need this way, and also I've done a lot of research about sympy but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, you just need to present the correct input. For

```
p(x) = 5x^10 + 9x - 7x - 10
```

you should provide:

```
poly2 = [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9-7, 10]
```

Alternate pol - implementation:

```
def pol(poly, x):
    n = len(poly) # no need to provide it at call

    rp = poly[::-1]  # [-10, -1, 9, 5] so they correlate with range(n) as power

    print("Poly:",poly, "for x =",x) 
    result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        val = rp[i] * x**i
        print(rp[i],' * x^', i, ' = ', val, sep='')  # debug output
        result += val

    return result

x = 2  # 1 is a bad test candidate - no differences for 1**10 vs 1**2

# 5x^3 + 9x^2 - x - 10 for x = 1
poly = [5, 9, -1, -10]
print("Value of polynomial is: ", pol(poly, x))

# p(x) = 5x^10 + 9x - 7x - 10
poly2 = [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9-7, 10]
print("Value of polynomial is: ", pol(poly2, x))
```

Output:

```
Poly: [5, 9, -1, -10] for x = 2
-10 * x^0 = -10
-1 * x^1 = -2
9 * x^2 = 36
5 * x^3 = 40
Value of polynomial is:  64

Poly: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, -10] for x = 2
-10 * x^0 = -10
2 * x^1 = 4
0 * x^2 = 0
0 * x^3 = 0
0 * x^4 = 0
0 * x^5 = 0
0 * x^6 = 0
0 * x^7 = 0
0 * x^8 = 0
0 * x^9 = 0
5 * x^10 = 5120
Value of polynomial is:  5114
```